# appendChild not in right place

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I want to apend a child ( `<tr>` ) to a table, after a specific row. because the rows get added by `while mysqli_fetch_array()`

I made a fiddle to show the problem. When you clic on add the text "abc" gets adedd. but behind the table, not as a new `<tr>` under the original row.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgpYS/13/)
How can this be solved.

Comment: `table` and `tbody` have also [`insertRow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow) method. Used together with [`rowIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement.rowIndex) of `tr` element, it should be fast enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/fgpYS/15/)***

You are inserting a child of the table row with append *Child*. That is why the placement seems to be "not in the right place". It is however, right where you asked it to be placed. Instead, you can use **[insertBefore<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)** like this:

```
ct.parentNode.insertBefore(tr,ct.nextSibling);
```

This will look at the parent of the row (`<tbody>`) and then insert the new row before the next row of the selected button. Essentially this is "insertAfter", but that feature was never implemented for whatever reason.

As to the claim that `insertBefore` is somehow slow and should be avoided or that `appendChild` is preferred, it would seem [that is not the case](http://jsperf.com/append-child-vs-insert-before).

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) okay, i dont wanted the "insertBefore" because it is slow, but then there is no ohter way :)

Comment: Isn't that what the answer does?

Comment: @user3108507 - It would seem that is actually not the case. You can see from this **[jsPerf demo](http://jsperf.com/append-child-vs-insert-before)** that appendChild is actually 31% slower.

Comment: okay in this case, i will always use insert. I was told insert gets slow...and i have to do it like 200 times. but if its fast, thats good. :D